# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

Having a bit of an issue that might be staring me right at the face.

```js
var listitem = document.createElement("li").id = 'list' + x[i]
var listitem = listitem.innerHTML = '<button id="delete' + x[i] + '" class="button action" onclick="deleteuser(\'' + x[i] + '\')">Delete</button>' + x[i]
document.getElementById('userslist').appendChild(listitem)
```

The bit of code is in a for loop on Javascript and from the error I can understand that the for loop is working as intended, but it's failing to append to the mentioned list with the error stated above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is wrong

```
var listitem = document.createElement("li").id = 'list' + x[i]
```

It ends up storing the string in the variable `listitem` and not the object.

Your code should be

```
var listitem = document.createElement("li");
listitem .id = 'list' + x[i];
```